# implementing parallax effect in amp-html

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I am having trouble implementing a parallax effect in amp-html. I have an amp-image with the property `background-attachment: fixed` but this doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Are you trying to get the background image to scroll slower than the foreground?

Comment: http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/ outlines a pure CSS approach for parallax. Not sure it's compatible with the amp subset, though.

Answer (score 1):

First-class parallax support is on the roadmap, but not yet implemented.

Comment: Please create a Github issue here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new asking for this feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use amp parallax effect script. Check out the link.

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/layout/amp-fx-parallax

Use the code

Add `<script async custom-element="amp-fx-parallax" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fx-parallax-0.1.js"></script>`
To your head and then add,

`<amp-img amp-fx-parallax="0" height="50vh" layout="fixed-height" src="your image"></amp-img>`

In your body.

This procedure is currently in development so might be unstable but can be used ☺. It might be updated later.